# Powershell delete files and leave text file

Tags: powershell, archive, delete-file

I am setting currently writing a script that will delete files over 700 days old. That bit of the script is working fine. I have tested it and it works. I have now been tasked with leaving a text file behind called "name of removed file" with details of how to contact service desk requesting that the file is restored. I have no idea how to go about doing this. So could you please help me?

Here is my deletion script:

```
foreach ($path in Get-Content "pathList.txt") {
    Write-Host "Trying to delete files older than 700 days, in the folder $path" -ForegroundColor Green
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include "*.*" | 
        WHERE {($_.CreationTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(-700))} | 
            Remove-Item -Force
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you'll need to pipe to `ForEach-Object` so you get a chance to make the text file you need for each file you delete.

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include "*.*" | 
    WHERE {($_.CreationTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(-700))} | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $text_file = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_, 'txt')
            "Call help desk blah blah" | sc $text_file -Encoding ascii
            $_ | Remove-Item -Force
        }
```

Comment: Will `[io.path]::ChangeExtension($_, 'txt')` throw an error if there is no extension on $_? I'm bad will aliases, sc = Set-Content.

Comment: @BobLobLaw give it a try :)

Comment: `New-Item -Path . -Name asdf -ItemType file | % {[io.path]::ChangeExtension($_, 'txt')}` Pretty cool! Guess who just learned something new, -> THIS GUY! <-